# Eliminate duplicates based on conditions from several columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

This is my dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","3454","3454","345","345","345"), date = c("05/01/2001", "02/06/1997", "29/03/2004", "05/2/2021", "01/06/1960", "29/03/2003"),
                 infarct1 = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE),infarct2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, TRUE,  stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Basically I need to keep just 1 patient ID (aka, eliminate duplicated `PatientID`), based on the most recent infarct (last `infarct==TRUE` [but any kind of infarct] based on `date`).

So the outcome I want would look like:

```
 df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","345"), date = c("29/03/2004", "05/2/2021"),
                     infarct = c(TRUE,TRUE), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Hope this makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(infarct = infarct1 | infarct2) %>%
  filter(infarct == TRUE) %>%
  group_by(PatientID, infarct) %>%
  summarise(date=max(date))
```

1. Create `infarct` variable.
2. Filter TRUE infarct.
3. Group.
4. Look for last time.

Comment: Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `infarct`.
x operations are possible only for numeric, logical or complex types
ℹ Input `infarct` is `|...`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: I have 35 categories of infarct, maybe is that?

Comment: cool I think it worked? it says this to me thought " `summarise()` has grouped output by 'PatientID'. You can override using the `.groups` argument"

Comment: If you have an error with  `|`, then use `any` function like this `infarct=any(inf1,inf2,inf3,...,na.rm = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 1):

You can turn the date to date class, `arrange` the data by  `PatientID` and `date` and get the last date where `infarct = TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(date)) %>%
  arrange(PatientID, date) %>%
  group_by(PatientID) %>%
  summarise(date = date[max(which(infarct))], 
            infract = TRUE)

#  PatientID date       infract
#  <chr>     <date>     <lgl>  
#1 345       2003-03-29 TRUE   
#2 3454      2004-03-29 TRUE
```

---

For multiple columns get the data in long format.

```
df %>%
  mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(date)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('infarct')) %>%
  arrange(PatientID, date) %>%
  group_by(PatientID) %>%
  slice(max(which(value))) %>%
  ungroup

#  PatientID date       name     value
#  <chr>     <date>     <chr>    <lgl>
#1 345       2021-02-05 infarct2 TRUE 
#2 3454      2004-03-29 infarct2 TRUE
```

**data**

I think you need quotes around data in `date` column.

```
df <- data.frame(PatientID = c("3454","3454","3454","345","345","345"), 
                 date = c("05/01/2001", "02/06/1997", "29/03/2004", "05/2/2021", "01/06/1960", "29/03/2003"),
                 infarct = c(TRUE, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: This is perfect thank you!! However, I have just edited the post because I made a mistake. I have several types of infacts, but I am interested just in the last infarct. How would you tweak this? - million thanks!

Comment: By last `infarct` do you mean get the last `TRUE` value from all the `infarct` columns ? Does the updated answer give what you want?

Comment: Gives me an error...

Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?)
In addition: Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` input `date`.
ℹ All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
ℹ Input date` is `lubridate::dmy(date)`.

Comment: @Lili It means that the data you have posted in the question is not what you actually have. If the `date` column is already of class `Date` then you can remove the line `mutate(date = lubridate::dmy(date))`.